# change css of a jquery datatable row based on date range filtering

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

i am trying to change the background color of a jquery datatable based on a date range....i tried to use $.fn.afnFiltering.push(...) to do the date range filtering...but cant figure out how to change the color of the filtered rows....

heres the code i am using to do the filtering...i tested this and the date range filtering works...

```
        //row filtering by date
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
function (oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
    var iFini = document.getElementById('dateStart').value;
    var iFfin = document.getElementById('dateEnd').value;
    if (iFini == "" && iFfin == "") {
        return true;
    }
    else if (iFini != "" && iFfin == "") {
        return true;
    }
    else if (iFini == "" && iFfin != "") {
        return true;
    }
    else if (iFini != "" && iFfin != "") {
        var sdate = new Date();
        var edate = new Date();
        var initialdt = iFini.split("/");
        var enddt = iFfin.split("/");
        var filterdt1 = aData[3].split(" ");
        var filterdt = filterdt1[0].split("/");
        var msg = "";
        if ((Number.parseInvariant(filterdt[0]) + 1 >= Number.parseInvariant(initialdt[0]) + 1 && Number.parseInvariant(filterdt[0]) + 1 <= Number.parseInvariant(enddt[0]) + 1) && (Number.parseInvariant(filterdt[1]) >= Number.parseInvariant(initialdt[1]) && Number.parseInvariant(filterdt[1]) <= Number.parseInvariant(enddt[1])) && (Number.parseInvariant(filterdt[2]) >= Number.parseInvariant(initialdt[2]) && Number.parseInvariant(filterdt[2]) <= Number.parseInvariant(enddt[2]))) {
            // msg = "initialdt: " + initialdt[0] + "/" + initialdt[1] + "/" + initialdt[2] + "====" + "enddt: " + enddt[0] + "/" + enddt[1] + "/" + enddt[2] + "====Filter:" + filterdt[0] + "/" + filterdt[1] + "/" + filterdt[2] + "/n";

                //need to change the style here...not sure how to address        
                //the individual row

            return true;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
);
```

i am also binding the fnDraw function as below...

```
 $("#dateStart").keyup(function () { $dTable.fnDraw(); });
 $("#dateStart").change(function () { $dTable.fnDraw(); });
 $("#dateEnd").keyup(function () { $dTable.fnDraw(); });
 $("#dateEnd").change(function () { $dTable.fnDraw(); });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the tr element using iDataIndex and fnGetNodes.

`var tr = oTable.fnGetNodes(iDataIndex);

$(tr).css('background-color', '#F00');`

oTable must contain the dataTable object.

`var oTable = $("#myTable").dataTable({ ... });`

Comment: ok so that worked...partially....now i have another issue...only the first page entries get highlighted....if i view all the pages and then sort by any columns the rest of the matching entries get hightlighted....what gives??

Comment: Check this simple example: [http://jsfiddle.net/codigoespagueti/AHswU/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/codigoespagueti/AHswU/1/). Is there any difference with your code?